# Overwriting values in a variable

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to Swift, with a jolted problem. I need to get a list of all documents in the firestore collection. To do this, I use this function:

```
@Published var chatList: String!

    func getDataFromDatabaseListenChat() {
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        db.collection("chatRoom").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
            } else {
                for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
                    self.chatList = document.documentID
                    print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

If there are more than one document in the collection, it turns out that the next document overwrites the previous one in the variable and at the output I get one element in the list. Tell me how to add all these documents to the array so that they can be used in the swiftui list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid force unwrapping where possible. The previous answer suggests using an array, which is correct. But for safety you should do the following:

```
var chatList = [String]()

func getDataFromDatabaseListenChat() {
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    db.collection("chatRoom").getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
        } else if let querySnapshot = querySnapshot {
            self.chatList = querySnapshot.documents.map { $0.documentID }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Avoiding force unwrapping is a good general rule, but it doesn't always apply.  Where you have already ascertained that the variable is not nil you can safely force unwrap.  Here you've already tested that there is no error so you can be confident that the snapshot is not nil, and so can safely force unwrap it.

Comment: Yes, you have determined there is no error, but you have not determined that querySnapshot is not nil. Perhaps it works just fine now. But what if in a few months the developers of Firestore decide that having nil data in querySnapshot with no error, is an acceptable way of showing there is no data? Then your app will crash. Prevention is always a better approach.

Answer (score 2):

You need

```
var chatList =  [String]()
```

Then

```
self.chatList = querySnapshot!.documents.map{$0.documentID}
```